# Passing an arbitrary number of args to a function

Tags: c, function, macros, variadic, variadic-macros

So basically, I would like to redefine this part of code using macros,

```
switch(count) {
case 0:
 variadic();
case 1:
 variadic(array[0]);
case 2;
 variadic(array[0], array[1]);
case 3:
 variadic(array[0], array[1], array[2]);
...
}
```

My constraint is that variadic is a function that CANNOT be passed a count, so I cannot pass the array by reference. This way works just fine, but I want to know if I can do this using a macro, or in a better way, I don't mind if the number of arguments is limited, since right now, I only handle 6 anyways.

Thank you.

Comment: How does `variadic` know how many arguments it was called with?

Comment: So you want `SOME_MACRO(count, array)` to expand to the above?

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't really, it just assumes x arguments were passed (variadic is a user defined function pointer)

Comment: @John3136 Yes, as calling variadic for a case 6 and above becomes a two-three lines big call, a mess all-in-all.

Comment: Put the above code into a `call_variadic()` function. Then do `call_variadic(count, variadic, array);`.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with a macro, because the macro can't access the value of `count` to expand into the appropriate code. So this `switch` is the best you can do.

Comment: Post how `count` value was derived.  That is where code can automate this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> something like variadic_(8, array), expanding to variadic(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5], array[6], array[7], array[8]);

Using boost preprocessor, you can simply do this:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/pop_front.hpp>

#define TO_ARRAY(_,N,V) ,V[N]
#define variadic_(C,A) \
   variadic BOOST_PP_TUPLE_POP_FRONT((BOOST_PP_REPEAT(C,TO_ARRAY,A)));
```

(Dropping `BOOST_PP_` for discussion)

`REPEAT(3,TO_ARRAY,array)` generates a count list, expanding to:

`TO_ARRAY(`#`,0,array) TO_ARRAY(`#`,1,array) TO_ARRAY(`#`,2,array)`

...where each `#` is some number you should just ignore (having to do with nested macros, but you really don't care about it).

With the defined `TO_ARRAY`, this expands to `,array[0],array[1],array[2]`; surrounding that with parentheses makes a tuple.  This has an extra leading comma that `TUPLE_POP_FRONT` strips off.

As a corner case, if you pass `0` in, this builds the tuple `()`, which `TUPLE_POP_FRONT` just maps back to `()`.

Comment: @Whiteclaws You're mistaken.  The Boost Preprocessor library uses only the C preprocessor, which is indeed C.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look!

Comment: This could also be done without a framework, but the solution would be about as complex as the thing you're using it for.  _That_ might be okay, if it saves you elsewhere, but given the scope of the question it's difficult to recommend such an approach.